# Can't update manifest.json for my android homescreen webapp

Tags: android, web-applications, manifest, homescreen

I can't seem to get the manifest.json (associated with my webapp on my android phone) updated.

I created a web page
Created the needed manifest.json file as:

```
{
    "lang": "en",
    "display": "fullscreen",
}
```

Included the link in the html of the web page

```
<link rel="manifest" href="http://yoursite.com/manifest.json">
```

Brought up the web page on my Samsung android phone in the browser (Samsung Internet 2.1) and clicked "Add shortcut to home screen"
All looked good.  The shortcut was on the Homescreen with the icon and took me to the webpage in fullscreen mode.

Now I am trying to change some things in the manifest.json.  I wanted to add start_url and add some URL parameters.  So I deleted the icon on the home screen, changed the code in the manifest.json on the webserver.  Loaded the webapge in the browser and added the shortcut to the homescreen.  But the url parameters were not passed to the webpage.

I did the same steps again, but with a manifest.json with a different url.  no dice.
Tried changing "fullscreen" to "browser".  Then delete Icon, add to homescreen, try again.  Nope - still in full screen mode.  I also tried a different file name for manifest.json.  As well as a different `<title>` on the webpage.

Try as I might, I can't seem to get a different manifest.json to be saved.

What am I missing/doing wrong????
I assume manifest.json is saved on the phone.  Can/should I manually delete it (Although I can't find it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think I figured it out.
My bad in thinking the manifest.json was applicable to more than just Chrome.
It looks like the manifest.json has nothing to do with my webapp behaving as it does.  But rather this meta tag:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

This tag is what makes the shortcut on the homescreen open the browser in fullscreen mode.  I believe this was originally made for safari(?) but adopted by the samsung browser i am using.